# How can I map two queries from junction objects into an instance of a custom object class that I need to return?

Tags: apex, map, junction-object

I need my getUser method to return an instance of the custom object class UserCTI. 
I need make two queries and map their results into the UserCTI object, or I can make a subquery within the primary query and map to UserCTI.

- **Object 1:** User (Standard Object)
- **Object 3:** Team (Custom Object)
- **Object 2:** Team_Assignment (Custom Junction Object with Lookup relationship to User & Team)

I have already accomplished this in a different manner but I am newer to Apex and SF and have not yet used Maps and I was attempting to refactor for an existing class of mine.

```
global class UserCTI {
        public ID uId;
        public String uName;
        public String uProfileName;
        public String uRoleId;
        public String uRoleName;
        public String uUserName;
        public List<String> uTeams;
    }
```

```
QUERY 1:
[SELECT Id, Name, ProfileId, Profile.Name, UserRoleId, UserRole.Name, Username FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()]
```

```
QUERY 2:
[SELECT Team__r.Name from Team_Assignments__c WHERE User__r.Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()]
```

```
ATTEMPT TO SUBQUERY
```

```
global static User getUser() {
     Insert Logic
     return ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one query with a subquery.

```
SELECT Id, Name, ProfileId, Profile.Name, UserRoleId, UserRole.Name, Username,
       (SELECT Team__r.Name FROM Team_Assignments__r)
FROM User
WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()
```

I'm assuming that the child relationship name for the Team Assignment to User lookup is `Team_Assignments`; if it's not the case, you can adjust.

You can then get each property you need to populate in a `UserCTI` directly from the resulting `User` object, save the team names, which you obtain by iterating:

```
UserCTI myCTI = new UserCTI();
// initialize, populate, query the User record...

for (Team_Assignment__c ta : myUser.Team_Assignments__r) {
    myCTI.uTeams.add(ta.Team__r.Name);
}
```

You'll have to make sure that `myCTI.uTeams` is initialized, of course, and copy all of the other data points you want.